# how to see how a C# array is laid in memory?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'd like to see how the C# array is laid in computer memory.

What I'd like to see is mainly two columns one with addresses second with array elements. Is it possible?

I'd like to start with 1D array but then I'd like to observe how multidimensional arrays are laid.

**Question**

How can I see it via VisualStudio ?

Comment: How things are put in memory in .NET is an implementation detail - ie you may find a difference between the CLR and Mono, or even between different versions of them.  Probably not, but it's possible.  As a .NET developer, you generally don't need to care either - for what reason are you trying to find out?

Comment: Why does this question is being closed ?  it is a question that every .net developer must know

Comment: I'm interested in manipulation on multidimensional arrays. This question is just to get know how to check the basics, before I dive in in multidimensional arrays. I cannot think about better/simpler rewording this question. Thanks Hans for very good answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the Visual Studio debugger to see the array layout.  A simple example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
        Console.ReadLine();  // Breakpoint here
    }
```

Use Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target = x86.  Set a breakpoint on the indicated line, press F5, when it hits use Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory 1.  Type `arr` in the Address box.  Right-click the window and select "4 byte Integer".  Looks like this:

[image]

The first word is the "type handle", its value is random, just ignore it.  You can no doubt guess the rest, you see the array Length and the array elements.

Comment: Hans , a commenter in the original question said : "_How things are put in memory in .NET is an implementation detail_" , Does it mean that an array _can_ be stored at memory in a NON-sequential memory cells ?

Comment: Hmm, it is an "implementation detail" when you don't know how it is implemented.  Array elements are always stored sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinDbg with sos or psscor extensions.