# C# Multidimensional array arrangement in memory

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

If a[,] is a multdimensional array in C#, does a[0,1] or a[1,0] come immediately after a[0,0] in memory. This is important for knowing what order to iterate over the whole multidimensional array in. If one does it wrong one will create constant cache misses and the wrong way should be very slow.

That is

```
for (int i = 0; i < count1; ++ i ) {
  for (int j = 0; j < count2; ++ j ) {
    do something with a[i,j]
  }
}
```

should have very different performance than

```
for (int j = 0; j < count2; ++ j ) {
  for (int i = 0; i < count1; ++ i ) {
    do something with a[i,j]
  }
}
```

and which one is fast and which one is slow depends on the answer to my question.

Comment: It is [0, 0] [0, 1] [0, 2] [1, 0] [1, 1] [1, 2].  So first snippet is best. You find out [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28815972/17034).  Favor jagged arrays for fast indexing.

Comment: [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [1,0 ] [1,1] [1,2]

Comment: @HansPassant How can Jagged arrays be faster to index into? One indexes into the "outer" array to get the location in memory of the "inner" array, which sounds cache inefficient (because you had to grab two distant locations in memory instead of one)? I am not trying to argue, just curious.

Comment: Two reasons.  The element address calculation is arr + N*i + j instead of subarr + j.  And the jitter can't eliminate the index bounds check on the higher dimensions.  Each element access costs 2 bounds checks, just 1 for jagged arrays.

Comment: Do you have any measurements on this, @HansPassant?

Comment: I have measured it, yes.  Nothing I'd ever publish because that would be so misleading, speed completely depends on the size of the array, the size of the element and the memory cache state.  Jagged arrays simply always get ahead due to the reduced need for bounds-checking.  Use Stopwatch to measure.

Answer (score 1):

Memory structure is sort of like [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [1,0 ] [1,1] [1,2] 
My suggestion Outer loop should traverse the first dimension, and inner loop should go for the second dimension. Its simpler that way...

Comment: Nothing to do with "simpler", speed is the key.  Locality of reference is a big deal to using the processor caches efficiently.